# Flagging questions for closure that are old?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I've noticed recently at least several posts have showed up in the Close vote queue; two of which were posted about a year ago and the other about three months or so ago.

Whoever flagged it, indicated that it was off-topic.

What's the overall view on flagging post that are considered "old", I recall when I was in my heavy flagging days early on, that old post that I flagged where generally not honored.

Here are the questions that spurred my inquiry.

1. [Points in polygon stops processing at 0% Any ideas how to fix it?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50075/points-in-polygon-stops-processing-at-0-any-ideas-how-to-fix-it)
2. [viewshed analysis QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136807/viewshed-analysis-qgis)
3. [Alternatives to Avenza Maps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217526/alternatives-to-avenza-maps)
4. [Why is SAGA kriging slower in QGIS than in SAGA itself?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144309/why-is-saga-kriging-slower-in-qgis-than-in-saga-itself)

Comment: The notice says it's too old to migrate, but you should still be able to select that it's Off-Topic and should be on another SE site.  It just can't be migrated by a mod to that other SE site.

Comment: Can you include links to one or more such questions so that we can investigate them, please?

Comment: Only questions asked within the last 60 days are eligible for migration but other forms of closure are available for all unanswerable old questions. Migration is the one I, and I think SE generally, least prefers nowadays.  I only migrate when a question asker asks me to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just some comments on your four examples:

1. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50075 - unanswered after near 4 years - not enough info to enable a potential answerer to answer and asker appears to comment along lines of "leave it with me" - good flag, good closure
2. [viewshed analysis QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136807) - unanswered after near 2 years - very unclear question - good flag, good closure
3. [Alternatives to Avenza Maps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217526) - recent question - seeks a software recommendation - I [think](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4062/115) such questions are best asked at the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) so I am happy to see it closed
4. [Why is SAGA kriging slower in QGIS than in SAGA itself?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144309) - unanswered after near 2 years - not enough info to enable a potential answerer to answer - good flag, good closure

I am keen to see us keep [Improving on 17,500 unanswered questions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4117) so please do not hesitate to flag/vote to close any, including old, questions that you come across if you do not think they are [on-topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

If you simply think that they do not show any research effort, are unclear or not useful for any other reason then you have a downvote that can be exercised to nudge the question towards the path of the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/215590).

Comment: I'm sorry for viewing this question only by now, but I would had answered the same as @PolyGeo♦. Out of curiosity, the "flagger" was me: ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjzWb.png))

Answer (score 4):

Overall, there isn't anything wrong with flagging 'old' questions, provided the reason for doing so is valid. As Midavalo and PolyGeo point out, the question is too old to migrate to another SE site, but that may not mean it should remain open either.

You may be seeing some flags on older questions if users are trying to reduce [the list of unanswered questions](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/improving-on-17-500-unanswered-questions); I certainly notice a spike of question closures in the review queue anytime that meta question is bumped or featured.