# How to handle an old question that's too specific?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I recently came across a fairly lengthy question from over four years ago:
[save features from openlayers to postgis via nodejs and websockets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68279/save-features-from-openlayers-to-postgis-via-nodejs-and-websockets)

I could answer the question, but at this point I assume the original poster has moved on, and the question is specific enough that an answer unlikely to be of use to anyone else.

While "too broad" is a close reason, "too specific" is not. How should a question like this be handled? (Or should it just be left as-is?)

Answer (score 6):

Over 800 people have looked at the question so it is probably worth answering as I expect many will have found it via google when looking for a solution to a similar question.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to [@iant's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4706/115), I think if you ever see a question that you can answer, please do so. Even if it is several years old. Just because the original poster may have left (in fact, they last visited the site in July 2017, so they will probably be back), doesn't mean other people won't benefit from your answer.

As per [Improving on 19,500 unanswered questions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4117/7424), we have a lot of unanswered questions on this site, and we will all benefit from as many answers as we can get.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a "too localized" close reason but it was considered obsolete and removed by [Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154).

If you wish to volunteer your time to answer the question in its present Open state, then I think you should do that.

If you think it should be closed, then I think a case for voting to do so as "unclear what you are asking" is easy to justify because 800 views and no answers in more than 4 years suggests that it is not straightforward to answer, and could benefit from some editing by its asker (or any user) to make what it is asking clearer.

I think that the responsibility for questions being answered does not rest solely with their potential answerers.  Whenever we ask questions, and they remain unanswered, I think we as their askers should always play a part in trying to get them answered either by continuing to try and make what is asked clearer, or by self-answering, even if that answer is just to summarize any progress made.

If the asker is experienced, and understands that they are asking a question which may have little value to the GIS community, because it is too localized to their own work, then I think they should consider self-deleting it.